# in app purchase swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchases

такой вопрос, планирую динамически добавлять объекты (беру с сервера, предположим, что это гифки) для продажи, все будут стоить одинаково, но столкнулся с вопросом : можно ли так делать ? или нужно создавать игровой баланс ?

насколько я понял, мне нужен тип non-consumable, как будет сделать правильнее : создать внутриигровой баланс (юзер сможет пополнять только его и за счет него будут идти покупки) или же создать один тип non-consumable и применять его для всех гифок (а так можно ?)

я еще не работал с внутриигровыми покупками, а на ру сегменте толком информации нет

Comment: Мне, когда делал встроенные покупки в приложении, помог этот курс: https://swiftbook.ru/contents/in-app-purchases-in-ios-11-swift/ правда, он доступен по платной подписке (не знаю, можно ли давать ссылку на платный ресурс), но там все хорошо расписано. Не остается после него вопросов для стандартных ситуаций.

Comment: тоже натыкался на него и смотрел, там рассматривается стандартная ситуация, а как обстоят дела с мои случаем ? насколько я понял, надо еще посылать скрин продаваемых товаров эплу, у меня же товары (в данном случае гифки) берутся с сервера, цена будет одна и та же, вопрос : можно ли будет отдельно каждую гифку покупать или же придеться делать некий внутренний "счет" и пополнять его

Comment: мне кажется, тут как раз стандартная ситуация: открываешь доступ к определенной игровой сущности за деньги. Думаю, не нужно делать "внутренний счет". К сожалению, я покупки делал один единственный раз и как раз полностью по тому самому курсу - мне там все подошло и код и объяснения зашли хорошо - сделал и детали все уже забыл )